# "they'd"/"there'd" be too much of "a distraction"/"distraction"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, quantifiers

What sentence is correct?

1

> They'd be too much of a distraction.

2

> They'd be too much of distraction.

3

> There'd be too much of a distraction.

4

> There'd be too much of distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one 'c' in *distraction*.

If you correct the spelling mistake, (1) is OK if you are referring to more than one thing or person that would be distracting.

(3) is correct if you are referring to a distracting situation.

> There'd [there would] be too much of a distraction if you had loud music playing all the time. (*It would* is probably more natural.)

Comment: What if the meaning of "too much" is drop? They'd be of a distraction. Is it correct?

Comment: How about the other one? There would be of a distraction. Are both two correct too?

Comment: No. _Too much_ requires _of_, but if you drop it, the _of_ has to be dropped too. **They'd be a distraction.** Similarly with _there would be_.

Comment: Sometimes people say "**Some event is of importance.**"  Could it be changed to "**Some event is of much importance.**"?

Comment: It is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, it could, though **of great importance** would be more likely.

Comment: So there could be a similar case that we say "***They would be a distraction.***" and "***There would be a distraction.***"

Comment: I've already told you that you can say either of those.